# Razor: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, razor

```
@{ int i = 4; }
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
   @:s is equal to @s
   @{ i++; }
}
```

I get "No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments" on the @{ i++; } line of code.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{ int i = 4; }
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
   @:s is equal to @s
   i++
}
```

or

```
@{ int i = 4; }
@foreach (string s in "1,2,3".Split(',')) {
   <text>is equal to @s</text>
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify why this works: Once you're in code, you don't need @{} anymore.  You go into Markup with "@:", but leave it at the end of the line, so you're back in code again.