# No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments in MVC3 Razor Format,

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In My project `<% if (Model.Folders != null){}%>` is working fine,when i convert this code to razor format ,i got the exception "No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments in MVC3 Razor Format," on my

```
Html.RenderPartial(ViewData["abc"] as string, Model);
```

I am Using Dynamic View

Comment: I got this error also at this line: `@{isAlt = !isAlt;}`. It is very weird, I just want to toggle boolean variable. Previously I have declare it `@{var isAlt = true;}` and used somewhere in the middle with `class="@(isAlt? "alt": string.Empty)"` which is used to style alternate rows in a table. There must be a reason...

Comment: I got the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466469/razor-no-overload-for-method-write-takes-0-arguments

Answer (score 7):

In Razor the `if` test should be like this:

```
@if (Model.Folders != null)
{
    <div>@Model.Folders</div>
}
```

and the `RenderPartial` like this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial(ViewData["abc"] as string, Model);}
```

or you could also use the `Partial` method which is equivalent and a little shorter:

```
@Html.Partial(ViewData["abc"] as string, Model)
```

Comment: when i use the "@Html.Partial(ViewData["abc"] as string, Model)", i am getting the following error "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax. "

Comment: @amir, your view is not strongly typed, so you cannot use the `Model` variable. Make sure your view is strongly typed to some model type: `@model AppName.Models.SomeModel` in top of your view.

Comment: its Stongly Typed,I have Used the "@model AppName.Models.SomeModel"

Comment: And did you pass some model in your controller action to the view?

Comment: yes i have IQueryable List for controller to view From The fake Repository

Comment: @samir, if you correctly used a view model the exception wouldn't state `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>` but `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<IQueryable<YourModel>>`. Reading this exception stack trace it means your view is not strongly typed.

Comment: I used inherits= System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Controllers.SomeModel> with MVC3 its was working with the same code ,but when i used this with razor @model AppName.Controllers.SomeModel then it won't

Comment: `Html.Partial` is *NOT* equivalent to `Html.RenderPartial`.  The former generates a temporary `MvcHtmlString`.  The latter writes directly to the output stream.  As the partial's content length increases, the performance impact of both approaches diverge.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, I solved it by wrapping my Html.RenderPartial as follows:

```
     <text>
         @{
           Html.RenderPartial(ViewData["abc"] as string, Model);
          }
     </text>
```

or

```
<div>
@{
Html.RenderPartial(ViewData["abc"] as string, Model);
}
</div>
```